# How can I show grouping in a WPF Data Grid with multiple levels?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am relatively new to WPF, so I understand about Styles and setters, but I am having trouble on this one.

I am using a WPF Data Grid and need to show multiple levels of grouping. I would like the 2nd and 3rd group levels to be more indented than the top level.

The following code will show group levels, but it shows them one right on top of the other and makes the fact that they are nested group levels impossible to tell.

```
<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Expander>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I get the group header to indent based on level?

Comment: Are you using an ICollectionView to do the grouping?

Comment: Yes, I am using the ICollectionView to perform the grouping.

Answer (score 12):

In case anyone from the future comes across this. I was able to have nested groups and style them so they weren't stacked on top of each other by doing the following.

Add property to the CollectionViewSource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding TestData}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="TopProperty"/>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="SubProperty"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then in the DataGrid XAML you have to specify 2 GroupStyles, and the second one will be used for the nested group. I added margins to the StackPanel of the second group to push the text to the right to make it seem like it was in the appropriate column.

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Border Background="#FF959595" BorderBrush="#FF727272" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="5,0,0,0">                                            
                                            <StackPanel   Height="23" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,0,0" Background="#FFE6E6E6">
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Border Background="#FF959595" BorderBrush="#FF727272" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                <StackPanel   Height="23" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,0,0" Background="#FFF3F3F3">
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="55,0,0,0" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
</DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

I was able to find more on this here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm from the future and this was exactly what I was looking for! The XAML which solves this doesn't seem terribly intuitive and the MS docs don't do an awful lot to elucidate.

Comment: I am back to the future.  This tiered expander was helpful and fits the solution I am working on.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found an imperfect workaround. If you add a margin on the left of your ItemsPresenter, every level is indented as you'd expect. Unfortunately, the column headers are no longer aligned with the content columns. I'm still looking for a fix for that...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (or the last time I checked), the WPF Datagrid does not support hierarchical grouping.

The closest I could find was [this](http://sweux.com/blogs/smoura/index.php/wpf/2009/06/15/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-iv-templatecolumns-and-row-grouping/).

This is why we went with the [Xceed DataGrid](http://xceed.com/index.aspx) in our app. Unfortunately, it's not free so that might not be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I already make use of ICollectionView and PropertyGroupDescription in order to add grouping, however, you must still use XAML to describe how the grouping will be displayed, otherwise you will not get any UI indication of grouping.

I am interested in how to setup the XAML so that I can represent multiple levels of grouping, preferably with some kind of indentation per group level or something like that....

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial goes in the right direction: [Multi Grouping in DataGrid](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/MultiGroupingInDataGridInSilverlight3Application08092009041116AM/MultiGroupingInDataGridInSilverlight3Application.aspx)
But sadly 'PagedCollectionView' is Silverlight.